# Why is 燃える + ゴミ = burnable? But the verb is not in ta-form

Tags: verbs, て-form, tense

I saw this in the book.
[image]

> 管理人{かんりにん}: 燃{も}える ごみは 月{げつ}・水{すい}・金{きん}の 朝{あさ} 出{だ}して ください。

I remember that If we want to use a verb as an adjective, we need to change a verb into the Ta-form, but this one is the verb in  a dictionary form. Why is that?

Comment: Where did you learn that it needs to be in Ta-form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shouldn't think about the past tense of the verb here, because it has a completely different meaning.

> 燃えたゴミ

Literally means "garbage that burned" (= burned garbage). So it cannot be used as a potential form to mean "burnable".

> 燃えるゴミ

Is the correct form to use. It literally means "garbage that burns" so it could be translated by "burnable".

Also, you should forget the idea that a past-tense verb is an adjective, its translation might look like it's an adjective, but it's still a verb and it should be seen as such, even though we translate it by an adjective to make the translation sound more natural.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank you so much, sir. (＞Д＜)ゝ

Comment: Despite the correct form being 「燃えるゴミ」, I wonder why "burn**able** garbage" is not 「燃え**られる**ゴミ」.

Comment: @jarmanso7 You're thinking too much in English terms. The Japanese language was not made with English as a reference.

Comment: Also, @jarmanso7, in this specific context, it's more like "garbage **to burn**".